# Get data from outside the root level of response

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I'm still kind of new to REST and haven't been able to figure this one out.

I have a response like this one:

```
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "Result": {
        "CustomerStuff": {
            "Name": "John",
            "State": "Oregon",
            "GetEmail": false
        },
        "eText": "Will only get paper mail. "
    }
}
```

I would normally save the response body as a string and then use a JsonPath to get what I need.

```
String responseBody = given().body().when().etc...;
JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(responseBody).setRoot("Result.CustomerStuff");
```

Then get what I need:

```
String name = jsonPath.get("name");
```

I can't figure out how to get the, "eText" value.  It's not in the same segment of the response.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I might miss something but can't you simply do `new JsonPath(responseBody).setRoot("Result")` and then call `jsonPath.get("eText")` ? CustomerStuff would be under `jsonPath.get("CustomerStuff")`

Comment: @ojciecmatki - The ONE thing I didn't try.  That seems so obvious now that I feel completely stupid.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(responseBody).setRoot("Result")
```

And then call `jsonPath.get("eText")` in order to get the value you want.
You can still access CustomerStuff with `jsonPath.get("CustomerStuff")`